# t4mvc not working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, t4mvc

Any changes to actions or controllers results in errors or, worse, bizarre behaviour when the app runs.

For example, adding a new Action to a controller resulted in an Html.ActionLink call in a view actually calling the action.

I didn't know what had hit me...

In both cases, the problem is solved by uninstalling and re installing the t4mvc package.

Is there something I have to do to make T4 templates work with VS 2012??!

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that the project was upgraded from MVC 3 to MVC 4.  It was working just fine in vs 2010 and MVC 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen issues running T4MVC in VS 2012.

"*adding a new Action to a controller resulted in an Html.ActionLink call in a view actually calling the action*"

That sounds like you simply didn't rerun T4MVC after modifying your controller. That's something that has always been needed, though there are some tools like [AutoT4MVC](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8d820b76-9fc4-429f-a95f-e68ed7d3111a) that do this for you on build. But that's not a VS 2012 specific thing.

Comment: I must have had the macro in VS 2010, and then forgot about it.  Anyway, this gets the biscuit.

Comment: I remember now:  I had installed Chirpy in VS 2010.  Memory... What was that?

Comment: http://chirpy.codeplex.com/, but I think it doesn't support VS2012 yet. AutoT4MVC does.